# why location service updates only after restart the mobile?

Tags: android, gps, location

I am getting the location using Geocode while set mock location.It works, but location service is not update in HTC one untill restart the mobile.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is about value for update time and update distance check this value on requestLocationUpdates set values somthing like this :

```
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
```